# Printf changing output each time that function is called

Tags: c

So, I have a C program that does some stuff. One, it prints a matrix that it reads from a file.

My problem: Some very specific printfs often don't show when being called, other times they only print part of what they are supposed to, and other times they print completely fine.

## Printing the matrix

It's a 5x5 matrix, and it sometimes prints completely fine, other times it only prints 2 lines, and other times it doesn't print anything. This function is called by a menu that takes user input.

```
void imprimirMapa(TipoLote matrizLotes[][COL], FILE *fptr) {
    fptr = fopen("../mapa.bin", "rb");

    fread(matrizLotes, sizeof (TipoLote), LIN*COL, fptr);

    for (int i = 0; i < LIN; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < COL; j++) {
            fflush(stdout);
            printf("%s", matrizLotes[i][j].reservaAtual.alojamento);
            printf("%c", matrizLotes[i][j].reservaAtual.eletricidade);
            printf("%c", matrizLotes[i][j].reservaAtual.numeroCampistas);
            printf("\t");
        }
        printf("\n");
    }

    fclose(fptr);
}
```

## Not printing at all

This is just some basic printfs for user input, the **first 2** printf's do not print at all, but it still takes user input, when I register user input, the 3rd printf already works fine.

```
 fread(matrizLotes, sizeof(TipoLote), LIN*COL, fptr);

 fflush(stdout);

 printf("********** Registar uma Reserva **********\n");

 printf("Escolha um lote a reservar (linha)\n");
 scanf("%d", &linha);
 printf("Escolha um lote a reservar (coluna)\n");
 scanf("%d", &coluna);
```

## Matrix being created

```
int main() {
    setlocale(LC_ALL, "Portuguese");

    char vazio[2] = ".";

    FILE *fptr;

    TipoLote matrizLotes[LIN][COL] = {};

    fptr = fopen("../mapa.bin", "rb+");

    for (int i = 0; i < LIN; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < COL; j++) {
            strcpy(matrizLotes[i][j].reservaAtual.alojamento, vazio);
            strcpy(&matrizLotes[i][j].reservaAtual.eletricidade, vazio);
            strcpy(&matrizLotes[i][j].reservaAtual.numeroCampistas, vazio);
        }
    }
    
    fwrite(matrizLotes, sizeof(TipoLote), LIN * COL, fptr);
    imprimirMenu(matrizLotes, fptr);

    fclose(fptr);


    return 0;
}
```

I'm running this code inside CLion with the minGW compiler.

Comment: Can you show where/how `matrizLotes` is defined before it's passed to `imprimirMapa`?

Comment: Yes, I've added it to the post @lurker

Comment: Hm. That raises additional questions. The `main` function you are showing is not the same one that uses the initial function you show that you had trouble with, correct? Also, I see you are copying strings into the structure at each array element. You don't do it the same way each time (one time you dropped the `&`). It may not be a problem, but I'm wondering now what the structure looks like and how the destination addresses are defined.

Comment: The reason there is no `&` in the first line is because that structure element is a single character, while the others are arrays of characters.

The function imprimirMapa is actually called by another function which is basically just printing a menu with options

Comment: @lurker I think I might have found the issue. I had a `system("cls")` right before the function is called, removing it is now giving me consistent output.

Actually have no clue on why this happens from a technical point of view since it's related because cls is meant to clean the screen.

Comment: *The reason there is no & in the first line is because that structure element is a single character.* That actually sounds like a problem to me. You can't `strcpy` `"."` (which is 2 characters, including trailing null) to a single character. It will overwrite the following byte with null. If you want the one character copied over, you should just assign it.

Comment: You should post the `TipoLote` structure definition

Comment: @lurker Thank you for letting me know. Fixed it accordingly.